# IntelliJ doesn't show project wide problems with Gradle multi-projects

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Gradle multi-project setup. A web application project depends on a Java library project. I open the root project in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2 (Community Edition).

If a change in the library project causes compilation errors in the web project then I would like to know right away. But the Problems view of IntelliJ does not show any errors unless I fully rebuild the project.

[image]

[Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-and-project-analysis.html#enable-project-wide-analysis) talks about a way to enable project-wide analysis of errors. But I don't have that option available (see my screenshot). Is project-wide errors not supported for Gradle multi-project setup?

Comment: This option is available only for IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

Comment: I have opened a support request to Jetbrains. One of their comments suggests that this feature is available only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.